# the return data in ajax success callback is json object or json String

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I got question on ajax success data argument.
There are two ajax request and corresponding controller method,both of two controller methods return json String to success function,in ajax,I set both of the dataType as 'json',so I guess they are completely the same.But one of them return as Json String which means I have to parse it to object first and the other is Json object directly.I am confused about it.Thanks a lot!

I record them in console,see the code.First three show ajax1 and corresponding console and controller,last three show ajax2 and the same.

ajax

```
oldpassword.on("blur",function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:path+"/sys/user/checkPass",
        data:{method:"pwdmodify",oldpassword:oldpassword.val()},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            //this one is json object directly
            console.log(data);
            console.log(typeof(data));
            console.log(data.result+"*****");
            if(data.result == "true"){
```

in cotroller

```
resultHashMap.put("result", "true");
return JSONArray.toJSONString(resultHashMap);
```

in console

```
{result: "true"}result: "true"__proto__: Object
object
true*****
```

ajax2

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:path+"/sys/user/userdelete.html",
    data:{method:"deluser",uid:obj.attr("userid")},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data){
        //receive as Json String
        console.log(data);
        console.log(typeof(data));
        console.log(data.result+"*****");
        data = eval("(" + data + ")");
        if(data.delResult == "true"){
```

in cotroller

```
boolean result=userService.deleteUserById(id);
if (result) {
resultHashMap.put("delResult", "true");
    return JSONArray.toJSONString(resultHashMap);
}
```

in console

```
{"delResult":"true"}
string
undefined*****
```

Comment: First of all, the right way to parse a json string is with `JSON.parse()` and not `eval()`.

Comment: What is the controller signature, like it's `return` type?

Comment: It is String,with @ResponseBody annotation